# About dpi and layout-swx

Tags: android, android-layout, dpi

I have an `ImageView 50x50dp`.

I want to make it look good for all screens so I create different pictures for `ldpi`, `mdpi` and so on.

For `mdpi` that image will be `50x50px`, for `ldpi (0.75) 37x37px` and so on.

I put those pictures in appropriate folders `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and so on.

But now I want to make different layouts for tablets like 7" and 10" and I use different folders like `layout-swXX` and `ImageView` is `100x100dp` in those layouts. And I would need a picture of `100x100px` for `mdpi`.

Should I make another set of pictures for another layout folder? If yes, where should I put them? Something like `drawable-mdpi-swXX`?

And please don't refer me to those "Supporting Multiple Screens" article, I read it several times, it doesn't provide information about my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need different sized images for different layouts and same dpi bucket, then you need to create two different set of images and name them differently and put in appropriate dpi folder.

In practice that means that for `50x50dp` layout you would create `image50.png` sets and for `100x100dp` layouts you would have `image100.png` sets (`image50` and `image100` are arbitrary names you can name your images whatewer you like, just give them different names)

So your drawable folders structure would look like

```
drawable-ldpi
   - image50.png (37x37 pix)
   - image100.png (75x75 pix)

drawable-mdpi
   - image50.png (50x50 pix)
   - image100.png (100x100 pix)

drawable-hdpi
   - image50.png (75x75 pix)
   - image100.png (150x150 pix)
...
```

And for layouts - in small ones use `image50` for drawables and in large ones `image100`